# I want To select Particular sentence from column using Like for creating view can anyone help me on this ,

Tags: sql-server

**#NEG MR Neg–Pending:** Oliver to arrange cutting of management keys and keys for tenants

**#NEG MR Neg– Pending:** Oliver to ensure the tenant has inspected the property before the move in date of 05/11/2014

**#NEG MR Neg– Pending:** Oliver to email copy of key release form and photocopy of keys held by mr….                                      This will be done Monday 27th Oct as well as references etc.

this is My column data and i want to get result of only from #NEG to next # sign that is

Result should look Like this

```
#NEG MR Neg–Pending: Oliver to arrange cutting of management keys and keys for tenants
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you need correctly... try this...

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(YourColumn,CHARINDEX('#NEG',YourColumn,0),
    CHARINDEX('#NEG',YourColumn,4)-1)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: HI zack ,     thanx for reply but this query gives an error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'

Comment: Not sure what the issue would be, as it works just fine on the test table I made for it. Is all of the data above(the 3 #NEG lines) in one cell or are each of them split into a different row? I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are looking to accomplish with this if each of those is a different row in your table. If they are different rows that's why that code didn't work, because it assumes that each row will have two instances of the #NEG.

Comment: Thanx Zack For Your Help ..  I sorted Out this error but there is still issue that in single column there is multiple data and i have to pickup data which start with #NEG and that full line thats is ... Very much difficult ...   I wrote some script with your help which i pasted below answer..

Answer (score 0):

...  select Replace(REPLACE(test,'$',''),'Mr Neg','')as test,
Replace(REPLACE(test2,'$',''),'Mr Neg','')as test2,
Replace(REPLACE(test3,'$',''),'Mr Neg','')as test3
--REPLACE(test2,'$','')as test2,REPLACE(test3,'$','')as test3 
From (
select substring(a.test,1,charindex('$',a.test,1))as test,substring(a.test2,1,charindex('$',a.test2,1))as test2
,substring(a.test3,1,charindex('$',a.test3,1))as test3 
 from (SELECT    replace(convert(varchar(150),SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('#NEG1',name,5),    CHARINDEX('$',name,7)+70) ),'#NEG1','')as test,
replace(convert(varchar(150),SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('#NEG2',name,5),    CHARINDEX('$',name,7)+70) ),'#NEG2','')as test2,
replace(convert(varchar(150),SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('#NEG3',name,5),    CHARINDEX('$',name,7)+70) ),'#NEG3','')as test3
,name 
FROM test3nov2014  where name like '%#neg%')as a
)b